# Mail.php doesn't work with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a problem my email php file doesnt work if i put this .htaccess code in

```
## Prevent directory listings
Options All -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

the function from sending an html file with a form to the php file doesn't work.
the form works with post and then in the php file i have.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST["name"];
$visitor_email = $_POST["visitor_email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
```

this code no longer works then. i guested its because of rewriting the url with the .htaccess,

- how can i work around this so my php script can run
- and the file directories are protected from viewing
- and that the php extensions is no visbile.

thanks for reading

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? You are sending data via `_POST`, so there is no params in url. Are you able to access this file via url?

Comment: doesn't %{REQUEST_FILENAME} already have file extension?

Comment: when i delete my htaccess from the root i can use the mail file but when i put it in the code doesn't work.

Comment: i'm not good with htaccess so sorry i wouldn't know that insanebits

Comment: tried on my own system, works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Insert this line just below `RewriteBase` line** to ignore your rewrite rules for POST requests:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```